# Knockout - Deleting item from ViewModel doesn't remove from DOM

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view model which contains a collection of objects, 'Files'.

Obviously this is bound to the DOM.

When I remove an item from the 'Files' collection I would expect the DOM to be updated to reflect this, but it doesn't update.

This is the JS that I use for removing an item from the 'Files' collection.

```
this.Delete = function(id) {
    for (var f = 0; f < this.Files.length; f++) {
        if (this.Files[f].ID() == id) {
            this.Files.splice(f, 1);
        }
    }
}.bind(this);
```

If I print the length of the collection to the console after calling Delete(id), I can see that an item *has* been removed.

So why does the DOM not update?

If I call ko.applyBindings(... then it *does* update, but my understanding is that I shouldn't have to call this every time the view model updates.

So what might I be doing wrong?

Also, I've tried it with Files as an observableArray and a standard array, without any difference.

**UPDATE:** here's the definition of the view model (well... the relevant part, anyway)

```
function Files(files) {

    var self = this;

    self.Files = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.Delete = function(id) {
        // find which index the specified ID exists at
        for (var f = 0; f < this.Files().length; f++) {
            if (this.Files()[f].ID() == id) {
                this.Files().splice(f, 1);
            }
        }
    }.bind(this);

    ...
}
```

I've also tried it with

```
self.Files = [];
```

and then changing every instance of Files() to just Files. No difference.

Comment: How is `Files` definied? It should be an `observableArray` otherwise it could work... You have said that you have tried with `observableArray` can you post that version of your `Delete` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have the observable array:

```
self.Files = ko.observableArray([]);
```

but you need to call `splice` directly on the observable array with `this.Files.splice`:

```
this.Delete = function(id) {
    // find which index the specified ID exists at
    for (var f = 0; f < this.Files().length; f++) {
        if (this.Files()[f].ID() == id) {
            this.Files.splice(f, 1);
        }
    }
}.bind(this);
```

otherwise you remove the item form the underlying array without KO knowing about the removal so it cannot update the DOM. See also the documenation [Manipulating an observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) section.

By the way the observableArray has a `remove` function which could greatly simplify your code:

```
this.Delete = function(id) {
    this.Files.remove(function(item) { return item.ID() == id; } );        
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: Jeez, so simple, and yet I've probably spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out. Many thanks, @nemesv.

Comment: One small modification needed to your this.Files.remove suggestion is that item.ID() should be simply item.ID (no parentheses). Thanks again.

Comment: You had `.ID()` in your sample... I've just copied and assumed that your `ID` property is a `ko.observable`

Comment: Yes, that's true, I *did* mistakenly have ID().